# helm join list from values file

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm looking for a solution to transform a list in my values.yaml in a comma separated list.

values.yaml

```
app:
  logfiletoexclude:
    - "/var/log/containers/kube*"
    - "/var/log/containers/tiller*"
```

_helpers.tpl:

```
{{- define "pathtoexclude" -}}
{{- join "," .Values.app.logfiletoexclude }}
{{- end -}}
```

configmap:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  exclude_path [{{ template "pathtoexclude" . }}]
  ...
  ...
</source>
```

The problem is there is missing quotes in my result

```
 exclude_path [/var/log/containers/kube*,/var/log/containers/tiller*]
```

How can I fix it to be able to have:

```
  exclude_path ["/var/log/containers/kube*","/var/log/containers/tiller*"]
```

I've try with:

```
{{- join "," .Values.app.logfiletoexclude | quote}}
```

but this give me:

```
exclude_path ["/var/log/containers/kube*,/var/log/containers/tiller*"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Double quotes should be escaped in `.Values.app.logfiletoexclude` values.

`values.yaml` is:

```
app:
  logfiletoexclude:
    - '"/var/log/containers/kube*"'
    - '"/var/log/containers/tiller*"'
```

`_helpers.tpl` is:

```
{{- define "pathtoexclude" -}}
{{- join "," .Values.app.logfiletoexclude }}
{{- end -}}
```

And finally we have:

```
exclude_path ["/var/log/containers/kube*","/var/log/containers/tiller*"]
```

Comment: You're right only need to escape double quotes! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I solved it:

in `values.yaml` (quotes don't matter):

```yaml
elements:
- first element
- "second element"
- 'third element'
```

in `_helpers.tpl`:

```golang
{{- define "mychart.commaJoinedQuotedList" -}}
{{- $list := list }}
{{- range .Values.elements }}
{{- $list = append $list (printf "\"%s\"" .) }}
{{- end }}
{{- join ", " $list }}
{{- end }}
```

in `templates/mytemplate.yaml`:

```golang
elements: {{ include "mychart.commaJoinedQuotedList" . }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, the following also worked for me without having to extra-quote the input values:

```
"{{- join "\",\"" .Values.myArrayField }}"
```

Of course, this only works for non-empty arrays and produces a single empty quoted value for an empty array. Someone knows a simple guard one could integrate here?

Comment: There is the `quote` function exactly for this case

Answer (score 1):

Fluentd allows what they call "shorthand syntax" for arrays in their configs https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/config-file#supported-data-types-for-values, which is a string with commas in it to separate values, like "value1,value2,value3".

So if you can assume there will be no commas in your values, you could save yourself the headache of double quoting with `'"..."'` and just do:

In your `values.yaml`:

```
app:
  logfiletoexclude:
    - /var/log/containers/kube*
    - /var/log/containers/tiller*
```

In your `_helpers.tpl`:

```
{{- define "pathtoexclude" -}}
{{- join "," .Values.app.logfiletoexclude }}
{{- end -}}
```

In your configmap:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  exclude_path {{ template "pathtoexclude" . }}
  ...
</source>
```